# The Heroku Scheduler doesn't let me schedule with free dynos

Tags: heroku, scheduler

All the dyno sizes listed in the dropdown cost money. Is there some way to guarantee that only my free dyno hours will be used? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Heroku Scheduler Add-On is `free` when you add it to a Dyno which is using the Free plan.

If you use Hobby the type of the One-Off Dyno will be `hobby` (which is not free).

The same applies to Standard or Performance, see [Heroku One-Off Dyno Type](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos#one-off-dyno-type)

> Apps using standard or performance dyno types will use a standard-1x dyno type in the one-off dyno.